No Access to Auto-Suppression
A user suddenly doesn't have access to the auto suppression config in email studio admin, although I can still see it as an admin. Which permission gives access to auto suppression?
Thanks in advance

I suspect a recent change indeed.
I usually set three roles for myself:
The two admins & a role where I hide stuff I dont use, including suppression lists.
I DO use autosuppression lists (which technically are not suppression lists) regularly and they have disappeared for me too - some time recently (so they did not fall under that umbrella).
So I could isolate:
Had the entire "Email / Subscribers/ Suppression List" menu on deny;
Now with the below settings (no deny & no other role that denies them either), I see them again.


I found these two permissions gave access to Auto-Suppression Configuration in a custom role I created:
Under Administration these two Categories:

General
Business Unit

*I did not dig further.  This could be refined.
